# corp blue css menu

Tags: css, menu, tabs

Css Tabs : [`http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/corp_blue_css_menu/`](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/corp_blue_css_menu/)

This worked perfect ! but not have selected tabs. how to add selected tabs to this ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to, for example apply `class="selected"` to one of the tabs, and it has a different background colour?

Comment: Default tabs is class="selected . after cilck in other tab selected changed. example : ajax DD tabs http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxtabscontent/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Change the appropriate selected tag from:

```
<li><a href="#"><span>Menu 6</span></a></li>
```

to

```
<li><a href="#" class="selected"><span>Menu 6</span></a></li>
```

Then change the background image of the corresponding class:

```
#tabs a.selected {
background:url("media/selected_bg.png") no-repeat left top;
}
```

Comment: i tested this. if #tabs a.selected { font-weight:bold; } worked ! but if #tabs a.selected { background:url("media/selected_bg.png") no-repeat left top; } not show any bakground!please see orginal link

Comment: The selected_bg.png is a placeholder for an image YOU have to create.

Comment: For create css tabs two background needed! <span> and <ul><li> and background is css sprite . problem is this.